# sed : extract multiple fields in random order

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a paragraph as below

> Hello, this is pattern1=somedata and pattern2=someotherdata and
>   something else after this along with pattern3=data_again and
>   pattern4=wellstilldata and nothing more.

And I am able to extract those patterns values with,

```
sed -r 's/.*pattern1=([^ ,]+).*pattern2=([^ ,]+).*pattern3=([^ ,]+).*pattern4=([^ ,]+).*/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4/' file.txt
```

but there are some cases where pattern will be in random positions , I mean there is no condition as such always pattern1 should come first and pattern4 should come at last and pattern string may not be pattern always but it will be one of the given pattern in above sed logic. their positions may vary but my above logic of extracting multiple fields from paragraph will only work if they are in order or else I have to re arrange them in order everytime.

But is there any we can modify above logic to work like irrespective of position of patterns and string is not "pattern" always but they will be in my sed logic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the patterns output in sequential order separated by tabs, you can stuff the matching line into the hold space, and then process each pattern sequentially:

**`sed -r -e 'h;s/.*pattern1=([^ ,]+).*/\1\t/;G;s/\n.*pattern2=([^ ,]+).*$/\1\t/;G;s/\n.*pattern3=([^ ,]+).*$/\1\t/;G;s/\n.*pattern4=([^ ,]+).*$/\1\t/;'`**

```
$ echo blahpattern2=pat2,blahpattern1=pat1 blahpattern4=pat4,pattern3=pat3 blah | sed -r -e 'h;s/.*pattern1=([^ ,]+).*/\1\t/;G;s/\n.*pattern2=([^ ,]+).*$/\1\t/;G;s/\n.*pattern3=([^ ,]+).*$/\1\t/;G;s/\n.*pattern4=([^ ,]+).*$/\1\t/;'
pat1    pat2    pat3    pat4
```

- `h` hold the line in the hold space
- `s/.*pattern1=([^ ,]+).*/\1\t/` replace the pattern space with `pat1\t`
- `G` append the original line
- `s/\n.*pattern2=([^ ,]+).*$/\1\t/` after the newline in the pattern space, replace everything with `pat2\t`
- etc

Gives you the patterns in the order you process them.

Comment: Hi! This was useful for me. However, I seem to get a duplicate entry for each such line i.e. for each line in a file that matches this, I get 2 identical lines of output. Do you know why this could be the case?

Comment: @YashChowdhary no ideas, unless there is an extra ‘p’ command in your sed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` and [look-behind zero-width assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
grep -Po '(?<=pattern1=)[^ ,]+|(?<=pattern2=)[^ ,]+|(?<=pattern3=)[^ ,]+|(?<=pattern4=)[^ ,]+' file
```

Test input :

> Hello, this is pattern1=somedata and and something else after this along with pattern3=data_again and pattern4=wellstilldata pattern2=someotherdata and nothing more.

Output :

```
somedata
data_again
wellstilldata
someotherdata
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex :

```
(pattern1=([^ ,]+)|pattern2=([^ ,]+)|pattern3=([^ ,]+)|pattern4=([^ ,]+))
```

See this [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kLrlnp/1)

Using the pipe character, you'll be able to match either pattern1 or 2 or 3... no matter what their order is.

Comment: The regex on it's own isn't useful.

Comment: Right, apparently all the text has to be matched for the sed command to work properly. I've been trying with [`^(.*?(pattern1=([^ ,]+)|pattern2=([^ ,]+)|pattern3=([^ ,]+)|pattern4=([^ ,]+)))*.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/kLrlnp/4), which shows the appropriate output in Regex101.com but still doesn't work with the sed command (looks like groups above 2 aren't captured for some reason). Any thoughts ?